# Fail to resolve: zxing library

Tags: android, zxing

I want to make a app that reads QR code. So I am trying to use a zxing library.

I got an ERROR message

`"ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.journevapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0"`

I put `MavenCentral()` in `repositories(bundle.gradle project)` and I also put url, `jcenter{ url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"}`. But it didn't work. How can I solve this?

My build.gradle looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to link the libraries -- this will increase the size of your app and make it impossible to upgrade `zxing` without rebuilding your app, instead you'd better call it using intent:

```
private static final String ZX_PACKAGE = "com.google.zxing.client.android";
```

And then somewhere in the scanning function:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(ZX_PACKAGE + ".SCAN");
    intent.setPackage(ZX_PACKAGE);
    intent.putExtra( "SCAN_FORMATS", "CODABAR,CODE_39,CODE_128");
    intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "ONE_D_MODE");

    // This flag clears the called app from the activity stack so the users
    // arrive in the expected place next time this application is restarted
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);

    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        e.getStackTrace();
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.install_zxing_title);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.install_zxing_message);
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                installZXing();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.no, null);
        builder.create().show();
    }
```

And just in case you don't have `zxing` installed, copy/paste the following:

```
public void installZXing() {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://search?q=pname:" + ZX_PACKAGE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    try {
        this.startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        // Hmm, market is not installed
        Log.w(TAG, "Android Market is not installed; cannot install Barcode Scanner");
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.no_android_market), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a typo in your statement

```
implementation "com.journevapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0"
```

should be

```
implementation "com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0"
```